# Google Maps Android API v2 application is crashing

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to get the sample code of Android '**Google Maps Android API v2**' working. I get the project built without errors. However, when I try to run the app in Everpad device , the app crashes immediately.
here is :

**- The java code**

```
   package com.dvp.android.gallery;

    public class GPS extends Activity {
          static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
          static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
          private GoogleMap map;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gps);
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
        Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
            .title("Hamburg"));
        Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(KIEL).title("Kiel").snippet("Kiel is cool").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

        // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
      }


}
```

- The Manifest:

  ```
      <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_bardo" android:label="@string/app_name">
          <activity android:name=".Acceuil"
                    android:label="@string/app_name">
              <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
              </intent-filter>
          </activity>
          <activity android:name=".Objets" android:label="Objets">  </activity>
          <activity android:name=".GPS"
                    android:label="GPS">
          </activity>
          <activity android:name=".Detail" android:label="Detail"></activity>
          <activity
                  android:name=".Galeries"
                  android:label="Galeries"
                  />
          <activity
                  android:name=".Evennements"
                  android:label="Evennements"/>
          <activity
                  android:name=".Infos"
                  android:label="Infos"/>
      </application>
      <meta-data
              android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
              android:value="AIzaSyA0HMTTGLqlYaq6jOuS0imbjt7GmUHyK0c"/>

      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />




          <uses-permission android:name="com.dvp.android.gallery.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
          <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

      </manifest>
  ```

  - The logcat output:

09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dvp.android.gallery/com.dvp.android.gallery.GPS}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4429)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at com.dvp.android.gallery.GPS.onCreate(GPS.java:23)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     ... 11 more
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that  is in the  element of AndroidManifest.xml
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at maps.ag.bb.a(Unknown Source)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at maps.ag.bb.a(Unknown Source)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at maps.ag.an.a(Unknown Source)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at maps.ag.bh.a(Unknown Source)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at maps.ag.bg.a(Unknown Source)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at bob.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:297)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:806)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1010)
09-27 12:42:49.466: E/AndroidRuntime(5542):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1108)

the XML :

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".GPS" >
      <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Please help me . thanks

Comment: post your xml file here....

Comment: in manifest have you add   <permission
        android:name="packagename.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

Comment: yes it exists in the manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to make your `Activity` extend **FragmentActivity** instead of **Activity**

This is because Google Map class has a fragment and for that you have to import **android.support.v4.** jar file... And add a map to your layout as a fragment you need to extends with **FragmentActivity**

Comment: I thought FragmentActivity has been depreciated, and now a fragment is implemented as an Activity (subclassed from) ?